# An error pops up when building an APK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzg;

This error message is shown when i'm tring to build an APK. 
What does it mean? and how can I fix it?

These are my dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.github.sillebille:dynamic-calendar:1.0.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: You have a lot libs. See this doc https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: @Ludy Astra-Germany I did it, still not working. Any idea what else can this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change **'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'** to  **'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'** and add **compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'**

app build.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
         // whats ever
         multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

// whats ever

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.sillebille:dynamic-calendar:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

and added in your project build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
    // whats ever
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```